# javascript ${variable} not read correctly

Tags: javascript

The `sayHiTo` function is working correctly, however the `doctorize` function's `${variable}` is not recognized.

```js
function caculateBill(billAmount, taxRate) {
  console.log('Running Calculate Bill');
  const total = billAmount * (1 + taxRate);
  return total;
}

// Function call. on **Run**
const myTotal = caculateBill(100, 0.13);
const myTotal2 = caculateBill(200, 0.13);
console.log(myTotal, myTotal2);

function sayHiTo(firstName) {
  return `Hello ${firstName}`;
}

function doctorize(name) {
  return 'Dr.${name}';
}

console.log(doctorize('dasol'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../base.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="./cf.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The sayHiTo function is properly using backticks. The doctorize function is using single quotes.